# How to use controller with table from DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio-2012

In my Licenses controller I used SQL scripts  to create table. Is there any way to make that table use my own controller and view models?

This is part of my Licenses controller:

```
var list = GetAllCompanyNames();
foreach(var lists in list) {
    if (lists.Value == licenses.companyName) {
        string connectionString =
            "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\aspnet-LicenseManager-20141219012740.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-LicenseManager-20141219012740;Integrated Security=True";
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            con.Open();
            using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + "company_" + lists.Key + " (CompanyID INT, companyName TEXT)", con)) {
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Couldn't find any solution on the internet.

Comment: Controllers should not have any scripts in them. Any database access should be in a separate layer. And what do you mean by "use my own controller and view models"? The database should have no idea about the website.

Comment: `Is there any way to make that table use my own controller and view models?` Could you elaborate more?

Comment: "Is there any way to make that table use my own controller and view models?" By this I ment that for example we create some kind of model and then in VS we can create controller that works with that model. Moreover among the controller VS creates View folder with html files and then with Seed method we can generate a table in DB. So I didn't use Seed method or created a model. I just created a table in DB with sql script and now I need to create a controller and that View folder with html files for my table to control it.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should *not* be doing database access. That's not the controller's job. By tying your controller to the data access, you have prevented them from easily being separated. A better approach is to put database access in a separate library, or at the very least a separate class.

You should define your models:

```
//All the properties of Product should be described here, Name, description, price etc
public class Product
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

Helper Library:

```
//This will contain handy functions for decreasing repetitive database code
public class MsSqlDatabaseHelpers
{
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand command, string connectionString)
    {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
           command.Connection = connection;
           connection.Open();
           dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
       }
       return dt;
    }
}
```

Repository (data access layer):

```
//This will have methods for getting models from the database and also inserting and updating them (not shown)
public class MsSqlStoreRepository : IStoreRepository
{
    private string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public MsSqlStoreRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("select id, name, description, price from products");
        var dt = MsSqlDatabaseHelpers.GetDataTable(command, ConnectionString);
        return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => GenerateProductFromDataRow(r)).ToList();
    }

    //I abstracted this logic out so we could reuse it elsewhere
    private Product GenerateProductFromDataRow(DataRow row)
    {
        return new Product()
        {
            Id = row.Field<int>("id"),
            Name = row.Field<string>("name"),
            Description = row.Field<string>("description"),
            Price = row.Field<double>("price")
        };
    }
}
```

Then you controller would be like this:

```
public class ProductsController
{
    private IStoreRepository StoreRepository {get; set;}

    //When the controller is created, we'll initialize our data access layer
    public ProductsController()
    {
        StoreRepository = new MsSqlStoreRepository(Config.ConnectionString); //normally you'd use Dependency Injection instead of constructor
    }

    public ActionResult List()
    {
        var products = StoreRepository.GetAllProducts();
        return View(products);
    }
}
```

Now you can must more easily swap out your data access layer with an alternative - maybe you want to also provide an `OracleStoreRepository` or `XmlStoreRepository`.

Notice that the database has no idea about the site or controllers. Same thing for the database layer, which should only know about the database.

Comment: what  is this IStoreRepository? @mason

Comment: and how should I access this database to view, delete rows, edit etc.. in web browser? @mason

Comment: @NikasŽalias `IStoreRepository` is an interface that your repositories will implement. You view layer codes against that interface, rather than directly against an implementation of `MsSqlStoreRepository`. That's what allows you to swap out different repository layers (`OracleStoreRepository` or `XmlStoreRepository for example) without needing to redo the code in your view layer. `IStoreRepository` should simply be an interface that defines the operations that all repositories need to implement in order to provide the necessary level of functionality to the UI layer.

Comment: @NikasŽalias That's increasing the scope of the question, so I'm not going to answer that here. But most of this code I took from a demo project I created and made available on GitHub called [FancyStoreDemo](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/FancyStoreDemo). In particular, check out [IStoreRepository](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/FancyStoreDemo/blob/master/src/FancyStoreDemo.DataRepositories.Common/IStoreRepository.cs) and [MsSqlStoreRepository](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/FancyStoreDemo/blob/master/src/FancyStoreDemo.DataRepositories.MSSQL/MsSqlStoreRepository.cs).