# How to create table in browser asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

we all know how to create new row on table when application is running on website.

But how to create new table in DB on browser? I'm looking for some kind of example on the internet, but can't find anything....

I need to create new table by my own one controller, model and view folder(Index.cshtml, Edit.cshtml, etc...)

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'in DB on browser'.  You can store database on the client side by using javascript to access local storage.  It's not really a database though.  If you mean create a table in a database on the server side, then what database are you using?  For SQL server you can use the 'insert table' command.

Comment: Im sorry, for my question... Yes I want to create a table in SQL database when running my application on web browser. I used this method to create table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476394/how-to-use-controller-with-table-from-db 
But I cant access it in browser (I don't have those view files (index, edit...))

Comment: Is your question more about how to create MVC Controllers, actions, and views then?  You should post the code you wrote to try to do this and then ask what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new table using ADO.Net. Have your table creation query in some string, create a Sql command using this query and then execute this.
A sample could look something like this -

```
        string createtableCommandString = @"CREATE TABLE Persons
                                            (
                                            PersonID int,
                                            LastName varchar(255),
                                            FirstName varchar(255),
                                            Address varchar(255),
                                            City varchar(255)
                                            ); ";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YourconnectionString"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(createtableCommandString, connection);
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```